# Moving routes/web.php file gives class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with the Laravel 5.6 framework and I want to move the routes file to another directory. I moved it to the `~/config/routes/web.php` from the original `~/routes/web.php` directory.

I then changed the `mapWebRoutes` method in my `RouteServiceProvider` to this:

```
Route::middleware('web')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('config/routes/web.php'));
```

Now when I try to start up laravel I get the error:

> In web.php line 14:
>                                 Class 'Route' not found

I already checked the aliases array in my `app.php` config file. There it's just the right class:

```
'Route'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
```

When I change my routes directory back to the original `~/routes/web.php` directory, every works.

I also tried to import the class into the `web.php` routes file like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Then I received this error when trying to start up laravel.

> In Facade.php line 218:
>                                         A facade root has not been set.

How can I make it so that I can move my routes file to another directory without getting this error?

Comment: use **->group(base_path('config' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'routes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'web.php'))**;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move them to a directory that isn't being scanned for a specific reason.

The `config` directory is specifically for config files and they get loaded very early in the process, before the providers ... that is how your application gets the list of providers to load, from the config file.

If you want to make a directory named `random` in the root of your project and put your routes there, just change the path appropriately in the `RouteServiceProvider` and you will be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::middleware('web')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('path/routes/web.php'));
```

But **path can not be config**,
 
For example **base_path('public/routes/web.php')** but not **base_path('config/routes/web.php')**